# How to route different webservers to different URL using nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

creating a website for my self and need to host projects.

Basically, i hhave different projects with different framework. ie, Flask, Django, Node.JS and some html file projects. I would like to host them at `projects.domain.com/<project name>`

I tried to set `server_name projects.domain.com/asdf` but in error.log it says,  `server name "projects.domain.com/asdf" has suspicious symbols`

Next up, i tried to nest location blocks (which i presume isn't how its supposed to be)

```
location /asdf {
  location /static/ {
    root blah blah;
  }

  location / {
    ..
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000 ;
  }
}
```

But, this errors out saying location static is outside asdf

Some suggested to `alias` instead of `root` in the location /static/ block, but that doesnt work too.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all a `server_name` can not contain URI segments. So a hostname or IP should be used as a value.

If you want to mix different local directories and proxy-locations a configuration could look like this.

**Notice:** Your location URI (/one, /two) will be appended to the root path.

The `root` directive can be used in every location block to set the document root.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

This is the reason why `alias` exists. With `alias` the location will not be part of the directory path. Check this out:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

```
server {


  server_name project.domain.com;
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

  location /one/ {
     alias/var/www/html/project1/;
     index index.html;
  }

  location /two/ {
     alias/var/www/html/project2/;
     index index.html;
  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm hosting a python project. So, I need to have a location / block and a location /static/ for each project. Could u pls show how to achieve that ? And instead of aliasing a path, I need to proxy it to a server